# Customize WKWebView long-press behavior for phone numbers to match Safari

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview

In safari when you long press a phone number you are offered a dialog with action options (call, message, whatapp, etc.).

I am trying to replicate this behavior in WKWebView. Currently on long press nothing happens, and text selection begins. My goal is to get the same pop-up as Safari to appear.

Example of the safari dialog:
[image: example dialog]

I'm working on a fork of https://github.com/react-native-webview/react-native-webview/blob/master/apple/RNCWebViewImpl.m to try and implement this.
This is the code currently in place to customize the text select actions:

```objectivec
@implementation RNCWebView
...
- (BOOL)gestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)otherGestureRecognizer {
    // Only allow long press gesture
    if ([otherGestureRecognizer isKindOfClass:[UILongPressGestureRecognizer class]]) {
        return YES;
    }else{
        return NO;
    }
}

// Listener for long presses
- (void)startLongPress:(UILongPressGestureRecognizer *)pressSender
{
    // When a long press ends, bring up our custom UIMenu
    if(pressSender.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
      if (!self.menuItems || self.menuItems.count == 0) {
        return;
      }
        UIMenuController *menuController = [UIMenuController sharedMenuController];
        NSMutableArray *menuControllerItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:self.menuItems.count];
        
        for(NSDictionary *menuItem in self.menuItems) {
            NSString *menuItemLabel = [RCTConvert NSString:menuItem[@"label"]];
            NSString *menuItemKey = [RCTConvert NSString:menuItem[@"key"]];
            NSString *sel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", CUSTOM_SELECTOR, menuItemKey];
            UIMenuItem *item = [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle: menuItemLabel
                                                          action: NSSelectorFromString(sel)];
            
            [menuControllerItems addObject: item];
        }
  
        menuController.menuItems = menuControllerItems;
        [menuController setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
    }
}

- (void)dealloc
{
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)tappedMenuItem:(NSString *)eventType
{
    // Get the selected text
    // NOTE: selecting text in an iframe or shadow DOM will not work
    [self.webView evaluateJavaScript: @"window.getSelection().toString()" completionHandler: ^(id result, NSError *error) {
    if (error != nil) {
      RCTLogWarn(@"%@", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error evaluating injectedJavaScript: This is possibly due to an unsupported return type. Try adding true to the end of your injectedJavaScript string. %@", error]);
    } else {
      if (self.onCustomMenuSelection) {
        NSPredicate *filter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"key contains[c] %@ ",eventType];
        NSArray *filteredMenuItems = [self.menuItems filteredArrayUsingPredicate:filter];
        NSDictionary *selectedMenuItem = filteredMenuItems[0];
        NSString *label = [RCTConvert NSString:selectedMenuItem[@"label"]];
        self.onCustomMenuSelection(@{
            @"key": eventType,
            @"label": label,
            @"selectedText": result
        });
      } else {
        RCTLogWarn(@"Error evaluating onCustomMenuSelection: You must implement an `onCustomMenuSelection` callback when using custom menu items");
      }
    }
  }];
}
```

I've been able to customize the select menu (i.e cut, paste..) with `UIMenuController`, but have not had any success getting this sort of menu to pop up.